# How to Extend the response time of the 3rd party URL in netsuite? i.e., to avoid SSS_REQUEST_TIME_EXCEEDED for large requests

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

My POST request to a 3rd party URL is taking about 58 seconds(Checked this by testing it using postman).
But netsuite is giving SSS_REQUEST_TIME_EXCEEDED error if the response time exceeds 45 seconds.What are the settings to be done to make netsuite accept more response time than 45 seconds.

An order has 50 items and so the third party url is taking 57 seconds to process and give response. These kind of cases couldn't be avoided in my requirement.Please help

Comment: Can you submit separate calls for each item or line you're processing, and then either handle all responses separately as they're returned, or wrap them in a `Promise.all()` so you can handle them together if that's needed?  What script type(s) are you using?

Comment: Your only option is split the query per item, because it's not a script that's timing you out, it's the function itself and there's no way to increase time from it. The script type really don't matter because it's not the script that's failing, it's the function.